# Change of base property for flat modules?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I've read the claim about base change for flat modules in several sources (Lang's *Algebra*, Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, A&M), but unfortunately it isn't proven anywhere. The claim is that

> Let $A$ be a commutative $R$-algebra, and $F$ a flat $R$-module. Then $A\otimes_R F$ is a flat $A$-module.

The proof is supposedly immediate, but sadly not to me. Is there a nice standard proof of the claim I could read? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It amounts to the following observation: if $P$ is any $A$-module,
$$P \otimes_R M \cong (P \otimes_A A) \otimes_R M \cong P \otimes_A (A \otimes_R M)$$
Hence, if we have a short exact sequence of $A$-modules
$$0 \longrightarrow P'' \longrightarrow P \longrightarrow P' \longrightarrow 0$$
the tensored sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow P'' \otimes_R M \longrightarrow P \otimes_R M \longrightarrow P' \otimes_R M \longrightarrow 0$$
is also a short exact sequence, by hypothesis, and via the isomorphism discussed above,
$$0 \longrightarrow P'' \otimes_A (A \otimes_R M) \longrightarrow P \otimes_A (A \otimes_R M) \longrightarrow P' \otimes_A (A \otimes_R M) \longrightarrow 0$$
is also a short exact sequence, hence $(A \otimes_R M)$ is a flat $A$-module.